# CountVectorizer values work alone in classifier, cannot get working when adding other features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification, countvectorizer

I have a CSV of twitter profile data, containing: name, description, followers count, following count, bot (class I want to predict)

I have successfully executed a classification model when using just the CountVectorizer values (xtrain) and Bot (ytrain). But have not been able to add this feature to my set of other features.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
CountVecTest = vectorizer.fit_transform(training_data.description.values.astype('U'))
CountVecTest = CountVecTest.toarray()
arr = sparse.coo_matrix(CountVecTest)
training_data["NewCol"] = arr.toarray().tolist()

rf = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', min_samples_leaf=10, min_samples_split=20)
rf = rf.fit(training_data[["followers_count","friends_count","NewCol","bot"]], training_data.bot)
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-7d67a6586592> in <module>()
      1 rf = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', min_samples_leaf=10, min_samples_split=20)
----> 2 rf = rf.fit(training_data[["followers_count","friends_count","NewCol","bot"]], training_data.bot)

D:\0_MyFiles\0_Libraries\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    245         """
    246         # Validate or convert input data
--> 247         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    248         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    249         if sample_weight is not None:

D:\0_MyFiles\0_Libraries\Documents\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I did some debugging:

```
print(type(training_data.NewCol))
print(type(training_data.NewCol[0]))
>>> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this the other way around and add your features to your vectorization. Here is what I mean with a toy example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import hstack, csr_matrix
```

Suppose now you have you features in a dataframe called `df` and your labels in `y_train`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[2,3],"c":['we love cars', 'we love cakes']})
y_train = np.array([0,1])
```

You want to perform a text vectorization on column `c` and add the features `a` and `b` to your vectorization.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
CountVecTest = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.c)

CountVecTest.toarray()
```

This will return:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

But `CountVecTest` now is a scipy sparse matrix. So what you need to do is add your features to this matrix. Like this:

```
X_train = hstack([CountVecTest, csr_matrix(df[['a','b']])])

X_train.toarray()
```

This will return, as expected:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

Then you can train your random forest:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', min_samples_leaf=10, min_samples_split=20)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

NB: In the code snippet you provided, you passed the label info (the "bot" column) to the training features, which you should obviously not do.

Comment: thank you very much! Managed to get it working. also needed to cast the dataframe to int but everything else was spot on

Comment: Glad it helped!